# Dependency Injection IDbConnection SqlConnection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have this exception raised **sometimes**:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'
```

I use the built-in dependency injection:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IDbConnection>(db => new SqlConnection(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConnectionString")));

    services.AddScoped<IAppConfigurationRepository, AppConfigurationRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IHomeworkingRequestRepository, HomeworkingRequestRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
    services.AddScoped<IHomeworkingRequestService, HomeworkingRequestService>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Before, I had already this error. The code `services.AddScoped<IDbConnection>` I changed to `services.AddTransient<IDbConnection>` and solved the issue. But now I have the error again.

**EDIT**

Please find the code when the exception occurs :

```
public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _connection;

    public EmployeeRepository(IDbConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAllActiveEmployees()
    {
        string query = @"
           SELECT
               FirstName
              ,LastName
              ,BusinessUnit
          FROM Employees";

        using (var db = _connection)
        {
            _connection.Open(); // <-- The exception is thrown here
            return db.Query<Employee>(query);
        }
    }
 }
```

Please also find the full stacktrace :

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Homeworking.Dal.EmployeeRepository.GetAllActiveEmployees() in C:\Users\florian.nouri\source\repos\Homeworking\Homeworking.Repository\EmployeeRepository.cs:line 42
   at Homeworking.Service.EmployeeService.GetAllEmployees() in C:\Users\florian.nouri\source\repos\Homeworking\Homeworking.Service\EmployeeService.cs:line 22
   at Homeworking.Service.HomeworkingRequestService.GetAllEmployees() in C:\Users\florian.nouri\source\repos\Homeworking\Homeworking.Service\HomeworkingRequestService.cs:line 23
   at Homeworking.Web.Controllers.AppController.Index() in C:\Users\florian.nouri\source\repos\Homeworking\Homeworking.Web\Controllers\AppController.cs:line 22
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
```

Comment: Are you sure that `AppConnectionString` connection string exists?

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Please add the full stack trace.

Comment: Pro tip: move reading of the configuration file out of the registration lambda, (i.e. `db => ...`), into the `ConfigureServices` itself. This way, you can read and verify the configuration value at application startup, and let the application fail at that point, instead of when object graphs are resolved.

Comment: @CodeNotFound : yes it exists

Comment: Why do you want to use DI with a *connection* and why the deprecated interface? Connections should be created only when needed and immediatelly closed/disposed. That's why all examples show code like `using(var conn=new SqlConnection(connString){}` Since .NET 2.0 ADO.NET classes inherit from abstract base classes, not interfaces

Comment: If you want to create database agnostic ADO.NET code inject a [DbFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory#creating-the-dbproviderfactory-and-dbconnection) and use `factory.CreateConnection();` to create the connection when needed. Far easier to use an ORM like EF Core though

Comment: @Florian why are you trying to use DI with a connection in the first place? Opening and closing connections doesn't cost anything since most ADO.NET drivers implement connection pooling. Keeping a connection open any longer than absolutely necessary accumulates locks and *blocks* other requests

Comment: @Florian connections are one case where you definittely care about scope and lifetime. It's also a case where you *have* to use factory methods if you want to use DI or DB-agnostic code

Comment: @Florian are you using Dapper?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple but good example on how to use Dapper with Structuremap and dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292438/simple-but-good-example-on-how-to-use-dapper-with-structuremap-and-dependency-in)

Answer (score 12):

```
using (var db = _connection)
```

This is bad. You create a new variable for the same connection, so after the using block is done, your connection will be disposed. You should not do this. If you use a container to create stuff, the container should dispose those instances it does not need any more.

Most likely, what is happening is that your `_connection` variable got disposed and any class that gets a connection from the container (in case of Scoped) or any class that has this variable already and uses it a second time because it's an instance field, will use the already disposed connection.

Comment: Using a connection with DI is worse. It means that a single connection will remain alive for a long time, accumulating locks and blocking other connections. There's no reason to use DI with connections as long as the ADO.NET driver provides connection pooling

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Worse than *what*? It's *already* used with DI. I'm just saying he's using DI wrong if he has using blocks. I cannot say what the best solution would be, either a `using` block, or DI, but both should not be combined in that way.

Comment: a better solution would be to use a factory as ADO.NET intended. Instead of using the .NET 1.1 interface, inject and use the .NET 2 [DbProviderFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/obtaining-a-dbproviderfactory#creating-the-dbproviderfactory-and-dbconnection)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos While I agree in general, I tend to answer the question asked. The problem stems from disposing something that was container-created. That is bad, regardless of object.